# Laravel how to get values from a table with an id from another table

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

i am having some trouble getting results from a query. it's the following. I have two tables, `tasks` and `task_interactions`. the table tasks stores the tasks, and the table task_interactions stores the history of the tasks, like a change of status, comments... The column `task_id` in the task_interactions table is the `id` in the table tasks.
The table tasks has the following columns: `id | project_id | task_type_id | related_block | created_by | assigned_to | start_date | due_date | task_priority | comments | status | created_at |updated_at` The status in this table will be deleted.

The table taskinteractions has the following columns:
`id`,`task_id`,`status`,`comments`,`created_at`

In the models i have created the following relationships:

Task Model:

```
public function taskinteractions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Taskinteraction');
}
```

Taskinteraction Model:

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Task');
}
```

And now the question:
I want to get all the tasks assigned to the authenticated user with status (in the table taskinteractions) equal to "In Progress".
I have tried a lot of different approaches with no good results.
I am a newbie and so i believe that the solution might be simple, but i no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `assigned_to` has the id of the user and a typical user table, try the following,`$tasks` is the array of tasks you want to get

```
$interactions = TaskInteractions::where('status','In Progress')->get();
$tasks = array();
foreach($interactions as $interaction){
    $task = $interaction->task;
    if((!(in_array($task, $tasks))) && (Auth::user()->id == $task->assigned_to) ){
        array_push($tasks,$task);
    }
```